# Узнать какой radiobutton выбран

Tags: jquery

Есть HTML

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" id="mode_c1" name="type" checked="" value="0">
    <label for="mode_c1"><span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;По Казахстану</label>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:10px;">
    <input type="radio" id="mode_c2" name="type" value="1">
    <label for="mode_c2"><span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;По городу</label>
</div>
```

Как узнать какой выбран `radiobutton`? 
 На какое событие повешать слушатель?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {

    alert(this.value);

});
```

Comment: Можно, кстати, использовать `:radio` вместо `[type=radio]`.